# What is the archive target member name in makefile?

Tags: makefile

What is the target member name in an archive in a makefile?

It is explained here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Archive-Members.html#Archive-Members
but I don't quite understand it since there's not a brief example.

If I have

```
target(name): name
       echo $%
```

`$%` is the automatic variable for target name.

If I use `make target`, this won't run

why? What is "target member name" actually?

Comment: You do understand that this is talking about `ar` files, right?

Comment: "If I use make target, this won't run" There's no rule to make `target`, you'll also need `target: target(name)`, although usually archives have an `.a` suffix so perhaps `target.a: target.a(name)`.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you link to specifically explains this, near the beginning.

> This construct is available only in targets and prerequisites, not in recipes! Most programs that you might use in recipes do not support this syntax and cannot act directly on archive members. Only `ar` and other programs specifically designed to operate on archives can do so. Therefore, valid recipes to update an archive member target probably must use `ar`.

So for example, to create an `ar` archive called `target` containing `name`, the commands would be

```
touch name
ar cr target name
```

As a `Makefile`, this is

```
target: name
    ar cr $@ $^

name:
    touch name
```

The `target(name)` syntax is useful when you want to manipulate the copy of `name` which is inside `target`.  For example, if `name` was rebuilt at some point, your `Makefile` might want to compare its date stamp against the date stamp of the `name` member within `target`, to decide whether you need to update the copy inside `target`.

```
target(name): name
    ar cr $@ $%
```

But this doesn't specify how to create `target` in the first place; as far as I can tell, you need a recipe like the one at the top of my example for that.

Comment: Any examples that work? I actually need something that works

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are looking for.  What currently doesn't work?